# chrome disable or change keyboard shortcut ctrl+shift+c developer tools console?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, google-chrome

How can I disable the Keyboard Shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> in Google Chrome to bring up the Developer Tools console?

I find myself trying to `copy`+`paste` content from the browser and mistakenly typing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> when I really want to do <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> instead.

How can I disable the current keyboard binding or change <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to do the same as <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> in Google Chrome?

Answer (score 11):

I've managed to make it work with [shortkeys](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shortkeys-custom-keyboard/logpjaacgmcbpdkdchjiaagddngobkck):

- Keyboard shortcut: `ctrl+shift+c`
- Behavior: Run JavaScript
- Javascript code to run: `document.execCommand('copy')`

Then just hit <kbd>Save</kbd> and reload tabs for the new setting to take effect.

Comment: costs 1.99 is a deal breaker. Just go to chrome extensions, shortcuts, then map ctrl+shift+c to a non intrusive extension. (ublock origin)

Comment: I agree, it was free at the time.

Comment: From what I'm seeing, the app is free and open source. What am I missing ?

Comment: doesnt make any sense

Answer (score 6):

## Edit:

The originally suggested solution is no longer available.

The one provided by [Paweł Prażak](https://askubuntu.com/a/991632/235915) currently work and actually copies the text to the clipboard.

---

I was able to successfully override the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> shortcut by using the Shortcut Manager extension and creating a new shortcut for the key combination.

You can then reassign it to trigger a host of pre-configured actions, or any javascript / bookmarklet code of your choosing. I don't really have any experience with javascript, so I can't really figure out how to make it act like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, but as far simply preventing it from bringing up the Developer Tools console, simply setting it to execute:

```
<script></script>
```

seems to work.

Comment: Shortcut Manager is a Chrome extension not a Plugin, see this SO question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16815389/what-are-chrome-apps-vs-plugins-vs-extensions-and-how-to-develop-them

Comment: Your link to the shortcut manager extension is a 404

Answer (score 5):

You can do that with [Shortcut Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shortcut-manager/mgjjeipcdnnjhgodgjpfkffcejoljijf/related?hl=en-US) and `document.execCommand('copy')` command, which were added to [Google Chrome 43+ (~April 2015)](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/04/cut-and-copy-commands?hl=en)

[image]

Comment: as of 2018 the Shortcut Manager is not there anymore, you can try [shortkeys](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shortkeys-custom-keyboard/logpjaacgmcbpdkdchjiaagddngobkck) but it has a very small user base.

Comment: Shortcut Manger is back as of October 2019.

Comment: @jhclark Shortcut Manager appears to have disappeared again.

Answer (score 2):

After attempting the shortkeys (Chrome Extension) approach and finding it unreliable, I was able to solve this problem using [AutoKey](https://github.com/autokey/autokey).

First, `sudo apt install autokey-gtk`. Then, launch AutoKey, create a new script, set the Hotkey to be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, the window filter to be `chromium-browser.Chromium-browser`, and the script contents to be `keyboard.send_keys('<ctrl>+c')`.

Once the script is saved, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in Chromium will copy to the system clipboard instead of displaying the dev tools.

Answer (score 2):

> After attempting the shortkeys (Chrome Extension) approach and finding
> it unreliable, I was able to solve this problem using AutoKey.
>
> First, `sudo apt install autokey-gtk`. Then, launch AutoKey, create a
> new script, set the Hotkey to be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, the window filter
> to be `chromium-browser.Chromium-browser`, and the script contents to be
> `keyboard.send_keys('<ctrl>+c')`.
>
> Once the script is saved, pressing
> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in Chromium will copy to the system clipboard instead
> of displaying the dev tools.

The above suggestion from [@Ollin](https://askubuntu.com/a/1160286/829702) worked for me but I had to change the **Window Filter** to: `google-chrome.Google-chrome`on Ubuntu 18.04.03 LTS

(Sorry don't have comment power)

Answer (score 1):

[disable-keyboard-shortcut](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-keyboard-shortcut/aidbmcboeighgdnilpdljbedbbiocphj)

This is super simple and elegant. It uses the Chrome builtin extension shortcuts menu `chrome://extensions/shortcuts` and adds shortcuts that do nothing. Only works for shortcuts including `ctrl` or `alt`.